# View consumer and producer statistics on shell : kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to kafka. I have been given a task to send 2kb message with optimized throughput and latency. i really don't know how to benchmark these two metrics and setup my cluster. I do not have any cluster monitoring tool to use but to see the statistics on the terminal when i started the producer and consumer. Can anyone please help me which script i can use to see relevant statistics on the consumer end while the data flow is in progress?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you check command-line tools that comes with Apache Kafka installation (bin/ directory). Those include `kafka-producer-perf-test.sh` and `kafka-consumer-perf-test` which can help you to test your cluster performance.

This article includes good examples: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Kafka-2-3-Performance-testing/ta-p/284767